# PHP Image upload issue

Tags: php

I upload an image from my site and it loads in a folder debatepic but by default the image is storing in not-webvisible status ,So everytime after upload i need to change the status as webvisible so that it can be viewed on my site
The **parent directory** is set webvisible but files inside this is not webvisible by default!
Details :

http://www.votefan.com/startdebate.php ( to upload image ) (need to sign up or login with 
username: andy password: andy123 )

the page where image can be viewed is

http://www.votefan.com/voteresult.php?debid=18
Godaddy team informed it is coding error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upload code in your program try changing the permission of the images. Refer below code:

```
<?php chmod("path_to_the_image", 0644); ?>
```

You can refer the php manual for chmod at http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @Gopi Try setting permission 0755 instead of 0644. Check the file permissions of the image after the upload is over and check it if it is set correctly to be visible by the browser.